# How do I configure a .NET Core 2.1 service fabric service to automatically use request and dependency tracking in application insights

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I've created a Service Fabric .NET Core 2.2 (NOT ASP.NET Core) stateless service using the V2 remote listener. How do I configure Application Insighjts to automatically perform request and dependency tracking. All the examples I can find show how to do this for ASP.NET Core via the ConfigureService method when setting up the http service listener but NOT how to do this when usiong the RPC V2 remote listener.

I've tried using TelemetryConfiguration and TelemetryClient to set this up (I'm aware that I can manually start Request and Dependency activities) but can't get the service to log dependency calls to other Azure resources i.e. service bus.

I also have another service fabric service with an http listener and have set that up via ConfigureService an it works great. I'd like my remote listener service to also track requests and dependencies. How do I configure the service to do this?

Comment: are you calling the extension method `ServiceContext.InitializeServiceFabricClient()`?  A code example of how you're setting up your AI Client would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationInsights SDK by default only captures Http requests and dependencies. If using remoting, then see this repo on how to capture Requests and Dependencies.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric